# Gnucash Asset Chart - Change 'End Date' to 'Yesterday' rather than 'Today'

Tags: gnucash, chart

I would like to have an asset chart to end on 'Yesterday' rather than 'Today'. I update equities based on yesterday's close value. Is there a way of hacking the scheme report code to

relative . yesterday

rather than

relative . today

?

Or syntax for (relative . today) -1    or something?

Or adding an option in the date drop down to 'yesterday' as well as 'today'?

Thanks
A

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest a way to modify the code underlying the GnuCash *Asset Chart* Report.  It's probably doable, but I haven't experimented with it myself.  I also note that, in the 8 days since this question was posted, no-one else has posted a response.

I'm going to proceed on the assumption that the real desire is to find a way to easily run a GnuCash report with a period-end date of "Yesterday" (rather than finding a way to delve into old computer code).

GnuCash offers a number of shortcut tricks to change a date field.  I suggest that using a couple of these shortcuts will achieve the objective.

So...

After selecting the *Asset Chart* report (actually, this will work for *any* report) from the GnuCash *Reports* menu:

1. Click the **Options** icon to bring up the configuration settings for the report.  Go to the *General* tab on that configuration window.
2. Click on the radio button next to the *End Date* field where you set an explicit end date.
3. Click in that date field.
4. Press **T** or **t** on your keyboard.  *This sets the date in that field to **Today**.*
5. Press **-** <the *dash* or *MINUS* symbol> on your keyboard.  *Change the date in that field to **one day earlier***.
6. Click **OK** to set the report running with that configuration.

This procedure sets *Yesterday's Date* as your report-end-date with only 4 mouse-clicks and two keyboard presses - including clicking on "Options" and "OK".  Even if you do this every day, it has to be comparable (or easier) than spending time and effort to identify the underlying code, modify it, and test the modified code (for one or more reports).

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to hack reports.

I've been using a hack that changes the definition of current and previous year in reports to start 1 July. It will be overwritten each time a new version of GnuCash is installed and it's unlikely to work with the next major release.

Find date-utilities.scm eg C:\Program Files (x86)\gnucash\share\guile\site\2.2\gnucash\app-utils\date-utilities.scm and update code block with a text editor as shown in: [Hack Financial / Fiscal Year in all Reports](https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2021-October/097880.html).

https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Custom_Reports